# need to display image of the user in the people picker, Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, 2013, visual-web-part, people-picker

In the people picker, the attributes it shows are name,designation and their online or offline status, Is it possible to display the image of the person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what your looking for:

http://sharepointadam.com/2010/11/18/import-user-profile-photos-from-active-directory-into-sharepoint-2010/

> Create an import PictureURL mapping
>
> Perform a full profile synchronization
>
> Run the Update-SPProfilePhotoStore PowerShell command
>
> Perform a full profile synchronization

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/6913d948-e3dc-4c81-9ba8-6f90cde099f9

for 2013 it should be similar!

> Note: You CAN use following SharePoint PowerShell cmdlet command to
>   perform the import operation:

```
Update-SPProfilePhotoStore -CreateThumbnailsForImportedPhotos 1 -MySiteHostLocation http://<YourServerName>/my
```

> The cmdlet was introduced in this fix:
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2394320  (14.0.5128.5000)
>
> You just map the thumbnailPhoto AD attribute with the Picture property
>   in SharePoint, then run the sync, finally run the cmdlet.
>
> create the Mapping in SP2010 or SP2013:  go to Central
>   Admin->Application Management->Manage Service Applications  select
>   your User Profile Service Application  select the People->Manage User
>   Properties tab  in the left-hand column, look down and select the
>   Picture property.  edit this - down the bottom is 'Add New Mapping'
>   and via the dropdown on Attribute, select thumbnailPhoto.  it should
>   then look like this:    User Profile Synch Connection
>   thumbnailPhoto    Import go back to the Manage User Properties and you
>   should now see    Picture    URL   thumbnailPhoto
>
> OK, so now Synchronization->Start Profile Synchronization. Let that
>   run through. Next you will want to double-check your
>   MySiteHostLocation. select My Site Settings->Setup My Sites grab the
>   entry from My Site Host Location - that is what we need for the
>   MySiteLocation parameter.
>
> so, on the SharePoint box, launch a SharePoint PowerShell, (run as
>   administrator). the command will be as per below, with your path
>   replacing "http:///my"

```
Update-SPProfilePhotoStore -CreateThumbnailsForImportedPhotos 1         -MySiteHostLocation http://<YourServerName>/my
```

> Now, go back to your mysite, select your profile and... voila!!  the
>   new picture has been pulled in from AD.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/lukeb/archive/2013/01/04/sharepoint-import-a-picture-from-ad-for-the-user-profile.aspx

and

http://costoda.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/sharepoint-2013-user-profile-service.html

Comment: is this for sharepoint 2013?

Comment: updated my answer! it should be very similar

Comment: Why Create an import PictureURL mapping twice?

Comment: sorry a thats a mistake! only need to do it once!